# How to retrieve data from Dataframe having recent date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
date        weight
10/30/2018  
05/25/2018  80
09/05/2018  74.6
09/05/2018  74.8
07/08/2018  25
```

How to retrieve weight for recent date ?

Scenarios are as follows:

1. If recent date have no weight then the weight for next recent date should be considered.
2. If recent date appear multiple times in dataframe it should consider maximum weight.

(or weight with respect to 1st appearance of date is ok..i.e,getting
    `74.6` instead `74.8` is also fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert values to datetimes, sorting per `date` by [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), forward filling possible missing values and last get lact value of `weight`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values('date')
df['weight'] = df['weight'].ffill()
print (df)
        date  weight
1 2018-05-25    80.0
4 2018-07-08    25.0
2 2018-09-05    74.6
3 2018-09-05    74.8
0 2018-10-30    74.8

a = df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('weight')]
#alternative
#a = df['weight'].values[-1]
print (a)
74.8
```